# How to make a file update?

Tags: flash, usb

I have an SWF on a USB pen that I would like to check a web server each time that I open it to see if there is a more recent version of the SWF. If there is I want the SWF to download it.

How does one goes about doing so? What can I use? Im absolutely clueless on this.

Comment: uh, you would have to build some sort of executable that auto-runs on the USB key.  Probably not the most economical way of doing things.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring Minibot states that s/he will be opening the file manually "each time that I open it"

Answer (score 0):

A SWF is limited in what it can do. Flash Player can't write to the local file system (excluding [Local Shared Objects](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/articles/lso/)).

You would need to use [AIR](http://www.adobe.com/mena/products/air/) to produce an executable which could download a remote SWF and save it to the local disk.

Comment: AIR is one possibility, but in fact you could use any framework/language that can create an executable.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is Windows, you need to look at the [autorun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun) file specification. This file needs to be located in the root directory, and you can use it to specify any program you want to run when the device is inserted. Please note that the feature can be disabled by the user.

The part to check if there's a new version and download it, etc... that depends heavily on the language you are using to develop such program.

Comment: I dont even know what can I use, and apart from running in osx and windows I dont really care as long its not overly complicated, thank you.

Comment: Since you are restricted to multiplatform, AIR is a good option. Create a separate "bootstrap" program. You could store your main program version in a separate file, and send it via a HTTP request to your server. In the server you check to see if that version is the latest version and if it isn't, offer to download the new version.